# Why XML has empty spaces instead data inside after serialization?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

After serialization sometimes xml files is filled with empty spaces. Why is it happen? 
My serialization code is:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableStorage));
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(storageName, false, myEncoding))
    {
       serializer.Serialize(sw, messages);
    }
```

This code serializes me messages into XML. 
SerializableStorage looks like:

```
[XmlRoot("Storage")]
public class SerializableStorage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets an array of server messages
    /// </summary>
    [XmlArray("Messages")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Message")]
    public List<NMessage> Messages
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Public constructor
    /// </summary>
    public SerializableStorage()
    {
        Messages = new List<NMessage>();
    }
}
```

NMessage class has all fields as public.

And deserialization if needed:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableStorage));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(storageName, myEncoding);
StoreMessages = (SerializableStorage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

I've attached an "empty xml" example [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8nUPANBkIdsS3lDQXNWSzV5ckk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: An example of the "*empty spaces*" would help...also, keeping in mind that XML was designed more for machine consumption and not human - does it *really* matter?

Comment: @Eminem I wouldn't assume that the single space in `<EmptyElement />` matches a description "xml files is filled with empty spaces" - you can't be a rapper _and_ a psychic, right?

Comment: Nice one :)...I dunno, just searched in google and found it. I geuss you are right :)

Comment: Example attached, see link above